# How to specify a literal initialiser for Stack or Queue?

Tags: c#-4.0

This:

```
List<string> set = new List<string>() { "a","b" };
```

works fine, but:

```
Stack<string> set = new Stack<string>() { "a","b" };
Queue<string> set = new Queue<string>() { "a","b" };
```

fails with:

```
...does not contain a definition for 'Add'
```

which does make me wonder why the compiler was dumb enough to ask for Add.

So, how *should* one initialise at a Queue/Stack constructor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Collection initializers are a compiler feature that call the `Add` method with each item you pass.
If there is no `Add` method, you can't use it.

Instead, you can call the `Stack` or `Queue` constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var stack = new Stack<int>(new [] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Answer (score 0):

in C# 6.0, you can do this:

```
var stack = new Stack<string> () {"a","b"};
```

with below extension method

```
public static class Util
{
    public static void Add<T>(this Stack<T> me, T value)
    {
        me.Push(value);
    }
}
```

[image]